# How to assign value into button and set the onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-button

[image]
 I would like to create a Pop-Out dialog which will be similar like above picture. All the button will have the text from a List of texts and when any specific button is pressed the respective image should load in the Image section below.

For example: I have the JSON data like shown below, Once the user clicks `Apple` button the Image section below should load the link https://test.com/images/apple.jpg. Any idea or tutorial to achieve this?

```
"Fruit": [
{
  "Title": "Apple",
  "ImageURL": "https://test.com/images/apple.jpg"
},
{
  "Title": "Orange",
  "ImageURL": "https://test.com/images/orange.jpg"
},
{
  "Title": "Banana",
  "ImageURL": "https://test.com/images/banana.jpg"
},
{
  "Title": "Watermelon",
  "ImageURL": "https://test.com/images/watermelon.jpg"
},
{
  "Title": "Strawberry",
  "ImageURL": "https://test.com/images/strawberry.jpg"
}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476200/5901903 You should search before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android custom Dialog with Button onClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476045/android-custom-dialog-with-button-onclick-event)

Comment: 1) parse JSON. 2) dynamically create the buttons. 3) set a click listener to each. 4) in the listenerdownload the image and set it into `ImageVIew`

Comment: this is not what i looking for. what i want is set the data from array list into the button, not only the onclick action

Comment: please read the question clearly before marking a question is duplicate

Comment: You can create model class for fruit and store your json values into it. Create array of fruit model class and using recyclview display buttons with name .And on click of button get current clicked view and display image according to that.

Answer (score 0):

add button into Linear layout using for loop Like this.

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.layout);
        for(int i=0;i<fruitList.size();i++)
        {
            final Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(fruitList.get(i).getName());
            button.setId(i);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position=button.getId();
                    imageView.setImageURI(fruitList.get(position).getImage());
                }
            });
            layout.addView(button);

        }
```

here is github library instand of linear layout you can use FlexboxLayout of this library to add multiple row with button.
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout